# subview running but not showing

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

From withing a UIViewController that is tied to a UIView (drawn in a nib file), i try to add another view, as a subview to the first view.

In case you are confused: UIViewController -> UIView + GraphView (extends UIView)

So i am saying:

```
GraphView *myGraphView = [[GraphView alloc] init];
graphView = myGraphView;
[self.view addSubview:graphView];
[myGraphView release];
```

I have also tried with `insertSubview`.

The UIView shows up and the GraphView subview is instantiated correctly (its properties are there and i can access its methods). But it never shows on the screen!
**Its `drawRect` method is never called** (i have an `NSLog` in there that never shows), even if i manually call `[graphView setNeedsDisplay]`.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you're setting the GraphView frame rectangle, it will not display if it's offscreen. Also you probably should be calling the UIView `initWithFrame:` initializer if you aren't.

Comment: Genius!
I only did "init" not "initWithFrame" and that alone did it.

Thanks!!